# Does the additive action of $kG$ distribute over a tensor product?

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose we have vector spaces $V$ and $W$ which are $kG$-modules for some field $k$ and group $G$. We have that the tensor product $V \otimes W$ is also a $kG$-module under the diagonal action
$$
g \cdot (v \otimes w) = gv \otimes gw.
$$
Since $V \otimes W$ is a $kG$-module, it seems that it should be the case that
$$
(g+h)\cdot (v\otimes w)=g\cdot (v\otimes w) + h\cdot (v\otimes w),
$$
but
$$
(g+h) \cdot (v \otimes w)=(g+h)v\otimes (g+h)w=gv\otimes gw +gv \otimes hw + hv \otimes gw + hv \otimes hw,
$$
and
$$
g \cdot (v\otimes w) + h \cdot (v \otimes w) =gv \otimes gw + hv \otimes hw.
$$
What am I misunderstanding? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equality sign after the "but" is wrong. The equality $p\left(v\otimes w\right) = pv\otimes pw$ is required to hold only for $p \in G$, not for $p \in kG$. (This is why the tensor product of two $kG$-modules is defined in terms of $G$, not in terms of the $k$-algebra $kG$; if you forget about $G$ but only retain the $k$-algebra $kG$ (without any choice of basis), then you cannot construct this tensor product.)